# What is the best way to resize only certain controls on a form?

Tags: visual-studio, vb6

I'm coding a chat/server client and I'm having some issues trying to get resizing working correctly.

I have a chat form that looks like this.

[image]

I'm wanting to keep the top labels, textbox, and buttons the same size and in the same exact spot. I want to adjust the chat textbox, the listbox, and the textbox at the bottom that you type the message to. The send button I want to stay the same size also and always to the right of the send textbox. I'm having a really hard time trying to figure out how to code the resizing part of the code.

I could really use some assistance I've tried many things like.

`txtchat.height = me.scaleheight - 100` adding the 100 in there to try and take off some for the controls on the top of the form. Also tried

`txtchat.height = me.scaleheight - txtsend.height - 100` and a ton of other things. I guess I just don't understand how this resizing works.

Comment: That's your opinion. VB6 is still the most used windows programming language. Why anyone would use .net is beyond me. Why would you program in a language that requires an entire framework to be installed in order to even run the program? I can distribute a couple of files with my exe in a setup that registers the ocx files and anyone can run my app anywhere without a framework. VB6 is still supported in all Windows versions. Including the upcoming Windows 9.

Comment: I haven't found a need for 64 bit applications. I do this stuff just for the fun of it and knowledge. With multithreading, I could still use .net controls as active controls in vb6. There are toolkits out there just for that purpose. As long as I can do all the things I like to mess with in VB6 there isn't a reason for me to learn .net.

Comment: Let me just put it to you this way. If you can't help with the original question stop talking. I'm asking advice on resizing my form. I am not asking for advice on what language is better than others. Stop wasting my time and move on.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: One can only wonder why people not interested in VB6 keep following the VB6 tag.  Could they be trolls?  I think they could!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said, this would be much simpler in .Net (Winforms has docking panels that automate this) but here's what you need to do in VB6:

I don't have VB6 installed so I'm not going to write out the code but the steps should be enough to get it right.

I assume txtSend is the textbox to the left of the Send button. To get the size of the chat box, you need to:

```
Bottom_area_height = Statusbar.Height + Statusbar_Padding + _
    txtSend.Height + txtSend_Padding
txtChat.Height = ScaleHeight - (txtChat.Top + Bottom_area_height) ' Fixed here
txtChat.Width = ScaleWidth - lstUsers.Width

txtSend.Top = ScaleHeight - Bottom_area_height
txtSend.Width = ScaleWidth - btnSend.Width

btnSend.Top = txtSend.Top
```

The padding values are the vertical gaps between the controls - the status bar padding looks like 2 grid cells and the padding for txtSend seems to be half a grid cell. You're not using the grid properly and it makes it very hard to see the distances of controls.

**Edit**

To add horizontal padding, just move the controls' left edge to where you want to have the left margin and then subtract the margin twice from the width of the textbox (to account for both margins).

```
txtChat.Width = ScaleWidth - (txtChat.Left * 2 + User_list_padding)
txtSend.Width = ScaleWidth - (txtSend.Left * 2 + Send_button_padding)
btnSend.Left = ScaleWidth - (btnSend.Width + Send_button_padding)
```

The padding values are the horizontal gaps between the controls, if you want any.

Comment: I'm getting some where with your suggestions but I had to alter it quite a bit to make it work. I'm only having issues with the padding on the right hand side of the listbox and the left side of the chat textbox. I'd like to have a little padding instead of it being directly against the sides. I'll put an answer with the code I've come up with for you to check out.

Comment: @FrostByte There was a typo in the answer - I updated it. `txtChat.Height` in the fixed line should be `Top`.

Comment: Okay so what about the lstusers in the new code? Do I need two txtchat.width lines of code?

Comment: @FrostByte What do you mean? The listbox's width can be calculated the same way as the `Send` button. Draw it out on paper with guides to see how the calculations work - it's very helpful to visualize it.

Comment: I got it just added the (txtchat.left * 2) after the lstUsers.Width

Comment: You left out the lstUsers in the new code you posted it has to be like this otherwise the chat box will just cover the listbox txtChat.Width = Me.ScaleWidth - lstUsers.Width - (txtChat.Left * 2)

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that. Once you get how one works, all other controls follow the same steps - simply subtract the top coordinate and anything below the control plus padding to get the dynamic height. Same goes for width, just horizontally.

Comment: I learned a lot from this thanks a lot. I should be able to do anything with my controls and forms now.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim intAreaHeight As Integer

intAreaHeight = stsBar.Height + 40 + txtSend.Height

txtChat.Height = Me.ScaleHeight - 1450
txtChat.Width = Me.ScaleWidth - lstUsers.Width

lstUsers.Height = Me.ScaleHeight - 1450
lstUsers.Left = txtChat.Width + 40

txtSend.Top = Me.ScaleHeight - intAreaHeight + 20
txtSend.Width = Me.ScaleWidth - cmdSend.Width

cmdSend.Left = txtSend.Width + 40
cmdSend.Top = txtSend.Top
```

This gets me this result as you can see the left padding and right padding is against the side of the form with no padding at all. I can't seem to figure out a good solution to get a padding.

[image]

**EDIT:
Updated code below worked great thanks for the help.**

```
Dim intAreaHeight As Integer

intAreaHeight = stsBar.Height + 40 + txtSend.Height

txtChat.Height = Me.ScaleHeight - 1450
txtChat.Width = Me.ScaleWidth - lstUsers.Width - (txtChat.Left * 2 + 40)

lstUsers.Height = Me.ScaleHeight - 1450
lstUsers.Left = txtChat.Width + 80

txtSend.Top = Me.ScaleHeight - intAreaHeight + 20
txtSend.Width = Me.ScaleWidth - cmdSend.Width - (txtSend.Left * 2 + 40)

cmdSend.Left = txtSend.Width + 80
cmdSend.Top = txtSend.Top
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

Just resize the ones you want resized.

Sounds "best" to me.  I've tried hoping Windows will read my mind but I haven't had any luck yet.

Comment: I honestly didn't know the controls at the top won't be messed with. I thought if I adjusted the size of the textbox it would cover the top controls. Knowing the chat will only go down, right, and left made this much easier then I thought it would be. I really thought that since the controls at the top of the form covered so much area that the area at the top had to be subtracted from the height of the listbox and chat textbox. I'm learning more and more ever day. So far I am loving this language.